# Simplify CTE for value from different years

Tags: sql, postgresql

perhaps someone knows if its possible to simplify my problem.
I have to get a value from different years - 2015- 2016 - 2017 - 2018.
For each year are different values(all in the same table (MY_TABLE), example:

```
DATE            VALUE
2015-01-12        K
2015-04-28        A
2015-07-11        M
```

I need to get the last value (in this example 'M') for each year.

My solution works, i´m just wondering if there is a cleaner and shorter one.

```
WITH CTE15 AS(
      SELECT a.*, row_number() OVER(partition by ID order by DATE desc) AS VALUE15
      FROM MY_TABLE
      WHERE DATE < date('2015-12-31')
     ),
     CTE16 AS (
      SELECT b.*, row_number() OVER(partition by ID order by DATE desc) as VALUE16
      FROM MY_TABLE
      WHERE DATE < date('2016-12-31')
      --and so for 2017 and 2018
     )
SELECT VALUE,*
FROM CTE15...INNER JOIN
     SOME TABLE
     ON KEY INNER JOIN CTE15
     ON KEY
WHERE CTE15.VALUE15 = 1 AND
      CTE16.VALUE16 = 1
```

An additional question:

```
DATE            VALUE
2015-01-12        K
2015-04-28        A
2015-07-11        M
2015-09-18        U
```

If the last value is 'U', how to ignore the 'U' and jump to the Value 'M'?

Comment: . . Remove the additional question so your question is not closed as "too broad".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (date_trunc('year', date)) t.*
from my_table t
order by date;
```

If you want the *nth* value, use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by date_trunc('year', date) order by date desc) as seqnum
      from my_table t
     ) t
where seqnum = <n>;
```

Comment: I think you'll need that date_trunc statement in the order by clause and since @HellaF10 wants the last date, I believe it should be `ORDER BY date_trunc('year', date), date desc`

Comment: I have tested it on my local machine and it work´s! This is a rly nice solution. Thank u @Gordon Linoff. Perhaps someone has a hint for my additional question, even if the question is not so important.

Comment: @HellaF10 . . . I think the second query answers your additional question.  If it doesn't you can ask another question with sample data, desired results, and an appropriate explanation.